# How to integrate banner ads of unity to flutter

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, flutter

I am trying to add banner ads to unity_ads_flutter plugin. But where can I add banner view to activity? Can anyone provide me some ideas and examples? The hard part is that I don't know how to integrate code in onUnityBannerLoaded(in the example) to flutter plugin.

This is a link to unity_ads_flutter plugin: https://github.com/EPNW/unity_ads_flutter
This is a link to unity guide: https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/android/integration-guide-android#banner-ads

Example Code from unity guide:

```
    public class UnityBannerExample extends Activity {
        private String unityGameId = “1234567”;
        private Bool testMode = true;
        private String placementId = “banner”;
        private View bannerView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
            setContentView (R.layout.unityads_example_layout);
            final Activity myActivity = this;
            // Declare a new banner listener, and set it as the active banner listener:
            final IUnityBannerListener myBannerListener = new UnityBannerListener ();
            UnityBanners.setBannerListener (myBannerListener);
            // Initialize the Ads SDK:
            UnityAds.initialize (this, unityGameID, myAdsListener, testMode);
        }

        // Implement a function to display or destroy a banner ad: 
        @Override
        public void ToggleBannerAd () {
            // If no banner exists, show one; otherwise remove the existing one:
            if (bannerView == null) {
                // Optionally specify the banner’s anchor position:
                UnityBanners.setBannerPosition (BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
                // Request ad content for your Placement, and load the banner:
                UnityBanners.loadBanner (myActivity, "banner");
            } else {
                UnityBanners.destroy ();
            }
        }

        // Implement the banner listener interface methods:
        private class UnityBannerListener implements IUnityBannerListener {

            @Override
            public void onUnityBannerLoaded (String placementId, View view) {
                // When the banner content loads, add it to the view hierarchy:
                bannerView = view;
                ((ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.unityads_example_layout_root)).addView (view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnityBannerUnloaded (String placementId) {
                // When the banner’s no longer in use, remove it from the view hierarchy:
                bannerView = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnityBannerShow (String placementId) {
                // Called when the banner is first visible to the user.
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnityBannerClick (String placementId) {
                // Called when the banner is clicked.
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnityBannerHide (String placementId) {
                // Called when the banner is hidden from the user.
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnityBannerError (String message) {
                // Called when an error occurred, and the banner failed to load or show. 
            }
        }
    }
```

To be more clear, I want to ask how to add the view returned from onUnityBannerLoaded

Comment: To be more clear, I want to ask how to add the view returned from onUnityBannerLoaded.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am trying to monetize my flutter app. I dont want to use admob can you suggest me what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue. You can follow our evolution of the plugin here:
[FlutterUnityAds](https://github.com/barracudapps/FlutterUnityAds/).

We also asked to the Reddit Flutter Community if someone can help us: [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/c7qc05/how_to_add_banners_in_an_fluuter_app_with/)

Hope we'll get some answers. Please, tell us if you find how to solve that problem.

Comment: did u find any solution?